# Is it possible to create a custom list in a public facing website on SharePoint Online O365

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-list, list-definition

I am trying to figure out of it is possible to programmatically (list definition/instance via solution) create a  custom list in a public facing website on SharePoint Online.
I have managed to create lists with PowerShell.

I would love to be able to use custom content types too but that seems to be not supported:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx?redir=0#_Toc355768412

Thanks,

David

Comment: Looking at your link, it seems that you are able to add apps to the public site.  Not sure if this will work, but try creating an app that creates the list using CSOM.

Comment: That would work, but then I prefer to write a PowerShell script.

Comment: Best way to find out is to experiment.